# Hibernate mapping List both sides relations.

Tags: java, hibernate, list

I have two objs; `Document` and `DocumentBatch`

**Document**

```
public class Document implements Serializable {

....
private String documentId; //PK of Document
private DocumentBatch documentBatch;
....}
```

**DocumentBatch**

```
public class DocumentBatch implements Serializable {


private String batchId;//PK of DocumentBatch

private List<Document> lDocuments = new LinkedList<Document>();
.....
public void insertDocument(Document document) {
    lDocuments.add(document); // lDocuments is a list DocumentBatch
    document.setDocumentBatch(this);
....}
```

**Hibernate mapping:**

**Document**

```
   <class name="Document" table="DOCUMENTS">
  .....
  <id name="documentID" column="DOCUMENT_ID" type="string" />
  <many-to-one name="documentBatch" class="DocumentBatch" not-null="false" 
  cascade="save-update" lazy="false" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="BATCH_ID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
  ......
</class>
```

**DocumentBatch**

```
 <class name="DocumentBatch" table="DOCUMENT_BATCHES">
     <id name="batchId" column="BATCH_ID" type="string" /> 
     <list name="lDocuments" table="DOCUMENTS" cascade="all"
        inverse="false" lazy="false" mutable="true">
        <key not-null="true">
            <column name="BATCH_ID" />
        </key>
        <list-index column="LIST_INDEX" base="0" />
        <one-to-many class="Document" />
       </list>
     ......
 </class>
```

DocumentBatch has a list of Document

Document has batchId which is PK of DocumentBatch. I have set in Hibernate mapping of the list in DocumentBatch with

inverse="false"

and in Document the many-to-one relation set  insert="false" update="false"

but when I try to save a Document obj, its DocumentBatch won't be saved.

How to solve. If someone could help .... hope all have a nice weekend.

**Oracle DB :**

Of Document

```
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENTS(
DOCUMENT_ID VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
BATCH_ID VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
...);  


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_DOCUMENT ON DOCUMENTS (DOCUMENT_ID); 
ALTER TABLE DOCUMENTS ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_DOCUMENT PRIMARY KEY (DOCUMENT_ID) USING INDEX PK_DOCUMENT); 

ALTER TABLE DOCUMENTS ADD (CONSTRAINT FK_DOCUMENT_BATCH_ID FOREIGN KEY (BATCH_ID) REFERENCES DOCUMENT_BATCHES (BATCH_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Of DocumentBatch

```
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENT_BATCHES(
BATCH_ID VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)     NOT NULL
...);

ALTER TABLE DOCUMENT_BATCHES ADD (
PRIMARY KEY (BATCH_ID));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I do understand you correctly. From the snippets you've shown I would say *the behavior which you are experiencing is correct*. You are saying that the problem is:

> but when I try to save a Document obj, its DocumentBatch won't be
>   saved.

Because there is explicit setting NOT insert and NOT update:

```
<many-to-one name="documentBatch" class="DocumentBatch" 
    not-null="false" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" 
    insert="false" // Hibernate do not insert
    update="false" // Hibernate do not update
>
```

Then the result is correct.
If you would like to save the relation to the `DocumentBatch` then just change that mapping:

```
insert="true" // Hibernate DO insert
update="true" // Hibernate DO update
```

*(or remove them, because default is `true`)*, And then if you will assign a `DocumentBatch` to your `Document` and save it - all will be persisted correctly. this should solve it.

#### EDIT: duplicated column exception

I am guessing that your entity `Document` has another field mapped to `batch_id`.

```
<many-to-one name="documentBatch" class="DocumentBatch" not-null="false" 
  cascade="save-update" lazy="false" insert="false" update="false">
  <column name="BATCH_ID" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
// this is not in the snippet above, but I guess it is there
<property name="batchId" column="BATCH_ID"/>
```

and in code:

```
public class Document implements Serializable {
private String documentId; //PK of Document
private DocumentBatch documentBatch;
// this is not in the snippet above, but I guess it is there
private String batchId;
....}
```

If this is the case, then two different properties are mapped to same column and that's why we are experiencing the: `duplicated column exception`
In case my expectations are correct, change the mapping this way:

```
<many-to-one name="documentBatch" class="DocumentBatch" not-null="false" 
  cascade="save-update" lazy="false" > // insert and update removed
  <column name="BATCH_ID" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
<property name="batchId" formula="[BATCH_ID]" insert="false" update="false"/>
```

So the `documentBatch` will be used for *insert* and *update*, while the batchId will be only for readonly.

Comment: well, when I try to remove  insert="false" update="false", Hibernate will inform me a duplicated column exception.

Comment: Makes sense. If there are two columns mapped, one of them must be readonly (insert and update false). So you most likely map the batch_id to some `int` field, right? place the insert update false there and change *column* mapping to **formula**. (I am guessing, because the snippet does not contain the second mapping)

Comment: you mean,  
<class name="Document"><many-to-one name="documentBatch" class="DocumentBatch" 
    not-null="false" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" 
    insert="false" update="false">
<formula>ANOTHER_COLUMN</formula></many-to-one>...</class>   Right?